# ASP NET MVC 5 Dapper com SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, dapper

Estou a criar uma aplicação com `ASP.NET` `MVC5`, `DAPPER`, `C#` E `SQL SERVER`.
O problema, é que na listagem dos dados, está a trazer os campos vazios, excepto o campo ID, que vem zero (0).

Se alguém souber a solução deste problema, agradeço imenso.

***Classe ClienteModel***

```
public class ClienteModel
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int Idcl { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome é obrigatório.")]
    [Display(Name="NOME")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "TELEFONE")]
    public string Telef { get; set; }
}
```

***Repositório:***

```
public class ClienteRepositorio
{
    public SqlConnection con;

    private void Conexao()
    {
        string strConexao = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LojaMVC5Dapper.Properties.Settings.SqlConexao"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(strConexao);
    }

    //para gravar o cliente
    public void GravaClienteR(ClienteModel cliM)
    {
        try
        {
            Conexao();
            con.Open();
            con.Execute("GravaCliente",cliM,commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        { throw erro; }
    }

    //para buscar os clientes
    public List<ClienteModel> BuscaClienteR()
    {
        try
        {
            Conexao();
            con.Open();
            IList<ClienteModel> listaCliente = SqlMapper.Query<ClienteModel>(con, "BuscaCliente").ToList();
            con.Close();
            return listaCliente.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        { throw erro; }
    }

    //para actualizar o cliente
    public void ActualizaClienteR(ClienteModel clienteM)
    {
        try
        {
            Conexao();
            con.Open();
            con.Execute("ActulizaCliente", clienteM, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        { throw erro; }
    }

    //para eliminar o cliente
    public bool EliminaClienteR(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            DynamicParameters param=new DynamicParameters();
            param.Add("@id",id);

            Conexao();
            con.Open();
            con.Execute("EliminaCliente", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            con.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        { throw erro; }
    }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
public class ClienteController : Controller
{
    //busca todos os clientes
    // GET: /Cliente/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ClienteRepositorio cliRepo = new ClienteRepositorio();
        return View(cliRepo.BuscaClienteR());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Cliente/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Cliente/Create
    public ActionResult GravaCliente()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Cliente/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GravaCiente(ClienteModel objCli)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ClienteRepositorio cliRepo = new ClienteRepositorio();
                cliRepo.GravaClienteR(objCli);
                ViewBag.Message = "Dados gravados com sucesso!";
            }

            return RedirectToAction("BuscaTodosClientes");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    // para editar os dados do cliente
    // GET: /Cliente/Edit/5
    public ActionResult EditarCliente(int id)
    {
        ClienteRepositorio cliRepo = new ClienteRepositorio();

        return View(cliRepo.BuscaClienteR().Find(cliente=>cliente.Idcl==id));
    }

    //pra actualizar os dados do cliente
    // POST: /Cliente/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActualizaCliente(int id, ClienteModel objCli)
    {
        try
        {
            ClienteRepositorio cliRepo = new ClienteRepositorio();
            cliRepo.ActualizaClienteR(objCli);

            return RedirectToAction("BuscaTodosClientes");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    //pra eliminar o cliente
    // GET: /Cliente/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection) 
    {
        return View();

    }

    //
    // POST: /Cliente/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EliminaCliente(int id1)
    {
        try
        {
            ClienteRepositorio cliRepo = new ClienteRepositorio();
            if (cliRepo.EliminaClienteR(id1))
            { ViewBag.AlertMsg = "Dados eliminados com Sucesso!"; }
            return RedirectToAction("BuscaTodosClientes");
        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("BuscaTodosClientes");
        }
    }
}
```

***View:***

```
@model IEnumerable<LojaMVC5Dapper.Models.ClienteModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Idcl)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Telef)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Idcl)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telef)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

***Apresentação:***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou iniciante em programação web, portanto, agradeço a vossa compreensão.

***Tabela Cliente:***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Observação:*** o nome da tabela é **CLIENTE**.

`Procedure` **BuscaCliente**:

```
    ---para buscar os clientes-----
create procedure BuscaCliente
as
begin 
select id_cl,nome_cl,telef_cl from CLIENTE order by nome_cl asc
end
```

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta com algum código?

Comment: Nos dê mais informações, o código por exemplo.

Comment: Ok. farei isso agora mesmo.

Comment: Adicione também a estrutura da sua tabela, seu nome, campos, etc. Além disto, `BuscaCliente` é o nome de uma stored procedure? Se sim, coloque o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edite a [Stored Procedure](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedimento_armazenado) e renomei os campos conforme o nome dos respectivos campos da classe `ClienteModel`. O [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) usa a relação de nome dos resultados obtidos com os da classe, ou seja, os *nomes precisam ser iguais*

```
alter procedure BuscaCliente as
begin 
    select id_cl as Idcl, 
           nome_cl as Nome,
           telef_cl as Telef 
    from CLIENTE order by nome_cl asc
end
```

Com essa alteração renomeando os campos igual esta na classe `ClienteModel` os resultados serão carregados.

**Referencias:**

- [Dapper dot net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/)
- [Dapper .NET Tutorial I](https://liangwu.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/dapper-net-samples/)
- [ADO .NET - Usando o Micro ORM Dapper .net](http://www.macoratti.net/15/12/adn_dapper1.htm)
- [Dapper and anonymous Types](http://Dapper%20and%20anonymous%20Types)
- [Procedimento armazenado - Stored Procedure](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedimento_armazenado)
- [GitHub StackExchange/dapper-dot-net](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

Comment: Muito obrigado @VirgilioNovic. Deu certo, agora está a trazer os dados conforme queria. Thanks Brother!!!